# Using ctypes to load a specific runtime library (MSVCRT80)

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

We're using `ctypes.windll` to load a third-party library. This library uses 'MSVCRT80' and states that it's callers responsibility to free resources. Therefor we've tried using `windll.msvcrt.free(pointer)` to free resources returned by the external library. This fails as `windll.msvcrt` is another runtime ('MSVCRT90.DLL' which Python is linked with)

Therefor we explicitly need to load 'MSVCRT80.DLL', but I can't find a way to load this library. I've tried using `ctypes.util.find_library('msvcrt80')` but this returns `None`. I guess this is because this function only looks through the path, while the actual library is located at `c:\windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_88e41e092fab0294`.

Is there any way I can load the correct runtime using `ctypes`?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the DLL could be passing on to you resources that you have to free by calling the `free` in the particular runtime that DLL uses.  That is exceedingly difficult to get right. Are you sure that the DLL doesn't export routines for you to call to free resources. If it is as you tell it I think you need to get the vendor to fix their design, or find a different library, or leak resources!

Comment: @David: unfortunatly there is no free-routines exposed by the API. It's horrible, but I think we'll have a hard time getting the vendor to fix this. The main cause why I think so is that this library usually is exposed only through a .NET wrapper - the C++ library is usually not distributed to customers directly.

Comment: Yeuch! One way to get it right is to use the activation context API. That's the clean way to make sure that `msvcrt80` is loaded correctly by ctypes. The messy way is to enumerate modules in the process and pick the right one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a workaround for this problem. After loading the external library, I enumerate over the loaded modules using `EnumProcessModules`, determine the filenames using `GetModuleFileName` and reference the correct module and load the `free()`-function from this runtime.

The code I'm using to do this is as follows:

```
from ctypes import *

def enumProcessModules():   
    # Get handle of current process
    kernel32 = windll.kernel32
    kernel32.GetCurrentProcess.restype = c_void_p
    hProcess = kernel32.GetCurrentProcess()

    # Load EnumProcessModules either from kernel32.dll or psapi.dll    
    try:          
        EnumProcessModulesProc = windll.psapi.EnumProcessModules
    except AttributeError:
        EnumProcessModulesProc = windll.kernel32.EnumProcessModules    
    EnumProcessModulesProc.restype = c_bool
    EnumProcessModulesProc.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_void_p), c_ulong, POINTER(c_ulong)]

    hProcess = kernel32.GetCurrentProcess()
    hMods = (c_void_p * 1024)()
    cbNeeded = c_ulong()
    if EnumProcessModulesProc(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), byref(cbNeeded)):
        return hMods
    return None

def getLoadedModule(moduleName):     
    kernel32 = windll.kernel32
    kernel32.GetModuleFileNameA.restype = c_ulong
    kernel32.GetModuleFileNameA.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p, c_ulong]

    modules = enumProcessModules()
    if modules is None:
        return None    
    for module in modules:
        cPath = c_char_p(' ' * 1024)
        kernel32.GetModuleFileNameA(module, cPath, c_ulong(1024))
        path = cPath.value
        if path.lower().endswith(moduleName):
            return module
    return None
```

To load the correct runtime and find the `free()` function I use the code above:

```
    runtimeModuleHandle = getLoadedModule("msvcr80.dll")
    runtimeModule = ctypes.CDLL('', handle = runtimeModuleHandle) # cdecl calling convention
    runtimeModule.free.restype = None
    runtimeModule.free.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]        
    myFreeProc = runtimeModule.free
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Hans' comment in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419544/writing-a-dll-that-loads-msvcr80-dll-and-exposes-the-free-function#comment-8967640), you can use GetModuleHandle to get the handle to the already loaded CRT.  Like this:

```
handle = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA('msvcr80')
msvcr80 = WinDLL('', handle=handle)
msvcr80.free(...)
```

For what it's worth, `windll.msvcrt` actually refers to the Windows system supplied C runtime, which is named `msvcrt.dll` and resides in your `system32` directory.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work as `GetModuleHandleA('msvcr80')` returns 0, even though the module has been loaded (it works with other modules, just not the runtime for some reason). However, this pushed me in the right direction; see my answer for the solution.

Comment: Funny, it worked absolutely fine for me. But I tested it with `msvcr90` because that's what my Python.exe was linked against.