# Writing a DLL that loads msvcr80.dll and exposes the free()-function

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, manifest, msvcrt

I have a third-party DLL that depends on MSVCR80 and allocates resources that I need to cleanup. The library does *not* expose a `free`-function for doing this. Instead, I need to load the same runtime library and manually call the `free` function.

As a workaround I'm trying to write a "wrapper" DLL that loads the correct runtime and exposes the `free` function. This DLL is created using Visual Studio 2010 and is dependent on a separate runtime library. Doing `LoadLibrary("msvcr80.dll")` fails with error R6034 which I guess is because of manifest issues.

Is it even possible to load msvcr80.dll using `LoadLibrary`? Do I need to create a manifest, embed it into the DLL and store msvcr80.dll in the same directory as my wrapper DLL?

I realize that this is a flaw in the third-party library, but I'm pretty much stuck with this version. Getting the vendor to fix this is most likely not an option.

Comment: See if these links help:  http://cowwoc.blogspot.com/2008/09/fixing-visual-studio-run-time-error.html, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235342%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Use the activation context api with the same manifest resource that is used by the miscreant dll. That will make the LoadLibray call work.

Comment: You need GetModuleHandle() instead since the DLL is already loaded.  Then GetProcAddress() to get the address of the _free function.

Comment: @hans the problem is what to pass as the module name. It's that lovely SxS thing. See the previous question.

Comment: @David - only the SxS directory name is complicated, an issue for LoadLibrary.  Not for GetModuleHandle, the module name is simply "msvcr80".

Comment: @hans you should write that as an answer

Comment: @larsm I've taken Hans' idea and applied it to your previous question. I presume you are still ultimately doing this through ctypes and Python. I think this means you don't need the C++ wrapper DLL that you are describing in this question. I've tested it out and it should all work beautifully from ctypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there are better solutions, but in case everything else failed you could find somewhere a copy of VC++ ***2005*** Express Edition (=free, no piracy is needed `;)` ), which uses the version 8.0 of the compiler, and thus the same runtime of the defective dll.

Then you would build your wrapper dll with it,  which would just call the `free` provided by its CRT (double check that you're using the dll version!).

Comment: VC++ 2005 Express is only free if you get it directly from Microsoft, and I don't think they offer it any more. Just because it was free doesn't mean it wasn't copyrighted, and nobody else has the rights to distribute it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that licensing restriction, still the 8.0 compiler should still be around in various packages still available on MS site (I recall it was used in the last DDK before they were renamed WDK).

Comment: Good idea and I would probably have ended up doing (something like) this, if I hadn't found another solution to my initial problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399774/using-ctypes-to-load-a-specific-runtime-library-msvcrt80 for details about the problem+solution I was working with).